# Tooltip is not hidden after formatting in highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I'm hiding the datalabels with 0 values by formatting it. It's working fine. But After formatting the tooltips with 0 valued data, when I hover in 0 valued part in pie chart, it show the whitebox as the mentioned in picture. I'm returning null as tooltip for 0 values.

[image]

here is the code:

```
.directive('hcPie', function() {
var firstValue = 1;
return {
    restrict: 'C',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div id="container" style="margin: 0 auto; width:70%; height: 60%;"></div>',
    scope: {
        item: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, filter) {
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: $(element).attr('id'),
                backgroundColor: '#F8F8F8',
                style: {
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, sans-serif'
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: "",
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    animation: false,
                    allowPointSelect: false,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '13px',
                            fontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, sans-serif',
                            fontWeight: 'normal'
                        } ,
                        formatter:function() {
                            if(this.y != 0) {
                                return this.point.name + ':' + this.point.sizeText;
                            } else {
                                return null;
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    showInLegend: false
                }
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter:function() {
                    if(this.y != 0) {
                        return this.point.name + ':' + this.point.sizeText;
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                data: [
                    {
                        name: 'Personal Files',
                        y: scope.item.personalUsage,
                        sizeText: scope.item.personalUsageSizeText
                    },
                ]
            }]
        });
    }
}
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. Returning `false` instead of `null` is working

```
 tooltip: {
        formatter:function() {
            if(this.y != 0) {
                return this.point.name + ':' + this.point.sizeText;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Return null doesn't make any sense you should return false inside the else condition.As return null will give empty tooltip and false will not create tooltip.

```
  tooltip: {
            formatter:function() {
                if(this.y != 0) {
                    return this.point.name + ':' + this.point.sizeText;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        },
```

Comment: yeah, I've figured it out as mentioned above. thanks.